# What is wrong with this IF NOT statement?

Tags: batch-file

This code is supposed to make it so that if I press 1 - 4 it would go the the options 1 - 4 and if i press something else it would say that its not an option. But if I type something else it goes to debug anyway.

And I've checked the code several times and I can't find an error. I even compared it to a code like this that actually worked and I even Ctrl-c Ctrl-v'ed it and it still won't work.

```
:admin
cls
color %debug%
echo You have accessed the admin debug menu
echo Do what you wan't
echo [1] Set Debug color
echo [2] Set Default color
echo [3] Set Warning color
echo [4] Exit
set /p "lol=> "
IF /i %lol%==1 goto dbg if NOT goto 9
IF /i %lol%==2 goto dfc if NOT goto 9
IF /i %lol%==3 goto wnc if NOT goto 9
IF /i %lol%==4 goto start if NOT goto 9

:dbg
cls
color %debug%
echo Set Debug color
set /p "debug=> "
echo Debug color set to %debug%
color %debug%
pause
goto admin

:dfc
cls
color %debug%
echo Set Default color
set /p "default=> "
echo Default color set to %default%
pause
goto admin

:wnc
cls
color %debug%
echo Set Warning color
set /p "warning=> "
echo Warning color set to %warning%
pause
goto admin

:9
cls
color %warning%
echo This is not a viable option!
ping localhost -n 5 >nul
goto admin
```

I test it out and when i type ex 5 it still goes to debug.

Comment: Your first `if` will, when corrected, go to `dbg` or `9`. It will not execute any of the other comparisons because execution will be transferred to either  `dbg` or `9`.

Comment: Please read the help of the `if` command by typing `if /?` into a command prompt window; you will find the `else` clause which you will need here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a closer look at how `IF` statements work.

E.g. this line `IF /i %lol%==1 goto dbg if NOT goto 9` makes absolutely no sense.

Your code should look something like this:

```
...
set /p "lol=> "
IF /i "%lol%"=="1" goto dbg
IF /i "%lol%"=="2" goto dfc
IF /i "%lol%"=="3" goto wnc
IF /i "%lol%"=="4" goto start
cls
color %warning%
echo This is not a viable option!
ping localhost -n 5 >nul
goto admin
...
```

Comment: The syntax is `IF [/I] [NOT] item1==item2 command`. So while `IF /i %lol%==1 goto dbg` is fine, the second part `if NOT goto 9` makes no sense. I assume `if NOT` should be `else`. `IF NOT` must be followed by a condition like `IF NOT "%lol%==5 GOTO XYZ"`. `IF NOT` is the batch variation of the `!=` operator known from other languages like C#, Java and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF /i %lol%==4 (goto start) else goto 9
```

Although it's normal practise to use

```
IF /i "%lol%"=="4" (goto start) else goto 9
```

which provides some protection against no entry or an entry containing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
IF /i %lol%==1 
(goto dbg) 
IF /i %lol%==2 
(goto dfc)
IF /i %lol%==3 
(goto wnc) 
IF /i %lol%==4 
(goto start)
else 
(goto 9)
```